# Converting Color and BackgroundStyle in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to do this where a background modifier could either accept an optional `BackgroundStyle` or a `Color`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var background: BackgroundStyle?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .background(background ?? Color.gray)
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView(background: .background)
}
```

I get this error and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

> Cannot convert value of type 'Color' to expected argument type 'BackgroundStyle'

Answer (score 0):

Because SwiftUI treats `Color`s as instances of View and `BackgroundStyle` is somethings that conforms to `ShapeStyle` such as: color, gradient, material, etc. You cannot use nil coalescing operator for different types.

You may want this approach:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
        }
        modifier(BackgroundModifier(background: background, defaultBg: .gray))
    }
}

struct BackgroundModifier: ViewModifier {
    var background: BackgroundStyle?
    var defaultBg: Color

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if let bg = background {
            content
                .background(bg)
        } else {
            content
                .background(defaultBg)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AnyShapeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyshapestyle) to erase the types, converting both `Color` and `BackgroundStyle` to `AnyShapeStyle`.

```
.background(background.map(AnyShapeStyle.init) ?? AnyShapeStyle(Color.gray))
```

The optional here makes this a bit messy. I would use a `Bool` instead, to indicate whether to use the background style. There is only one instance of `BackgroundStyle`, anyway.

```
let useDefaultBackground: Bool

...

.background(
    useDefaultBackground ? AnyShapeStyle(.background) : AnyShapeStyle(Color.gray)
)
```

Comment: The idea works but my problem is background is optional so I can't directly convert it to AnyShapeStyle.

Comment: @BerryBlue I literally showed how to do that in the first code snippet of my answer. `Optional.map` is designed for this.